# Which is the greatest (Inequalities)

Tags: inequality

Here are three different inequations,
$$A+B < C+D$$
$$B+D < A+C$$
$$A+D < B+C$$

Which is the greatest among $A,B,C,D$?

I do have a hunch on how to solve this, but don't know how the solution below would make sense,
$$A+B-D < C$$
$$B+D-A < C$$
$$A+D-B < C$$
this might say $C$ is greatest when I substitute value but how or does this even make sense, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the first two inequalities yields
$$A+2B+D<A+2C+D$$
$$2B<2C$$
$$B<C$$
Do the same with other pairs of inequalities.